# Shutdown the LED of my GY-85 sensor

Tags: gyroscope

I would like to shutdown the LED of my GY-85 (gyroscope) component. Is it possible?

Comment: use black paint

Comment: it's about energy, not visual comfort

Comment: next time you ask a question, please include that kind of information in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this schematic](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/GY-85/GY-85-SCH.jpg), no. The LED is connected directly to power.

You will need to physically remove the LED to turn it off.